# Defining completely separate style information

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I am building a collection of Web Applications. All these web apps have same header and footer. (Except their content change a little when a user signed in).

What I don't like is the feeling the usage/redefinition of a style information in the app which was defined for header or footer. If that happens, I may need rename style information in the app.

I have some solutions for this.

1. Using iframe for header and footer. So they never mixs up.
2. Use inline style information for header and footer.
3. Use very complex CSS definition name like sE69621C09. So in an app, I never use same name for for style information by mistake.

I am not sure about iframes. Some people says they are not secure. Well all web apps will be written by us, but I don't know if javascript can be used to some bad things in the server.

Inline style information can increase the amount of data transferred at every request.

Complex CSS name can confuse me if I look at same code months later.

What kind of techniques do you guys use while mixing different codes parts in same page to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to separate the style information from the app completely, and maintain separate stylesheets for each app.

So your header would use generic style identifiers, e.g.

```
<div class="header">
    <h1 class="maintitle">...</h1>
    <p class="slogan-text">...</p>
</div>
```

Each site then defines these styles in it's own stylesheet, i.e. Site1 has a file containing it's specific styling in `site1-styles.css`, Site2 in `site2-styles.css`, etc. Only include the stylesheet relevant to the specific site.

Avoid the repetition of style information for different sites in the same `.css` file.

Comment: Well, thank you though, this wasn't the answer I was looking for. This doesn't solve my problem. Anyway, I think I have found the solution. It is using > (greater than) symbol in css and binding definitions to body. In this way, CSS never mixes outside of header and footer. Thank you anyway.